# Inequality about joint probability distribution

Tags: probability, inequality

> Let $(\Omega,\sigma,P)$ be a probaility space, and for $k\in\{1,\cdots,d\}$, $X_k:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable. Prove that the joint distribution $F(x_1,\cdots,x_d)$ follows the inequality:
>   $$\small0 \leq F(x_{1}+h_{1},\cdots,x_{d}+h_{d}) - \sum_{k=1}^{d}{F(x_{1}+h_{1},\cdots,x_{k-1}+h_{k-1},x_{k},x_{k+1}+h_{k+1},\cdots,x_{d}+h_{d})}\\\small
> + \sum_{j < k}{F(x_{1}+h_{1},\cdots,x_{j-1}+h_{j-1},x_{j},x_{j+1}+h_{j+1},\cdots,x_{k-1}+h_{k-1},x_{k},x_{k+1}+h_{k+1},\cdots,x_{d}+h_{d})}\\
> \small- \sum_{i < j < k}{F(x_{1}+h_{1},\cdots,x_{i},\cdots,x_{j},\cdots,x_{k},\cdots,x_{d}+h_{d})} + \cdots + (-1)^{d}F(x_{1},\cdots,x_{d})$$
>   with each $h_{k}>0$ for $1 \leq k \leq d$.

I have read this as the third statement of a theorem, the first statement was that $F(x_{1},\cdots,x_{d})$ is monotomically increasing in each argument, and the second one was that $F(x_{1},\cdots,x_{d})$ is right continous in each argument. I have been able to solve the first and second statement but not the third one.

For the case $d=1$ it reduces to $0 \leq F(x_{1}+h_{1}) - F(x_{1})$, that is true for been monotomically increasing.

For the case $d=2$ it is:

$$0 \leq F(x_{1}+h_{1},x_{2}+h_{2}) - F(x_{1},x_{2}+h_{2}) - F(x_{1}+h_{1},x_{2}) + F(x_{1},x_{2})$$

and defining the events:

$$A = \{ω \in \Omega \mid X_{1}(ω) \leq x_{1}+h_{1} \text{ and } X_{2}(ω) \leq x_{2}+h_{2} \}\\
B = \{ω \in \Omega \mid X_{1}(ω) \leq x_{1} \text{ and } X_{2}(ω) \leq x_{2}+h_{2}\}\\
C = \{ω \in \Omega \mid X_{1}(ω) \leq x_{1}+h_{1} \text{ and } X_{2}(ω) \leq x_{2}\}\\
D =\{ω \in \Omega \mid X_{1}(ω) \leq x_{1} \text{ and } X_{2}(ω) \leq x_{2}\}$$

we can rewrite in terms of probability:

$$0 \leq P(A) - P(B) - P(C) + P(D)$$

now, for definition, $B \subset A$, so $P(A)-P(B) = P(A-B)$, and $(A-B) \cap D = \emptyset$, so $P(A-B)+P(D) = P((A-B)\cup D)$, and finally, using that $C \subset ((A-B)\cup D)$ we have  that $P((A-B)\cup D)-P(C) = P(((A-B)\cup D)-C)$. Puting all together we get:

$$P(A)-P(B)-P(C)+P(D)=P(((A-B)\cup D)-C) \geq 0$$

I have not been able to generalize this for an arbitrary d, I have tried induction but can not find the way of going from d to d+1. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Show that the right-hand side is the probability of the event $\{\omega \in \Omega \mid x_1 < X_1(\omega) \le x_1 + h_1 \text{ and } x_2 < X_2(\omega) \le x_2 + h_2\}$ (which must be nonnegative).

Comment: A MathJax hint: `\{` yields $\{$.

Comment: @angryavian is that in case d=2? I have already solve that, my doubt is  about a general d.

Comment: @Saad I have tried to use \{ but did not work, thanks for editing.

Comment: @DiegoYupanqui Sorry yes that is $d=2$. In general, it is $\{\omega \in \Omega \mid x_j < X_j(\omega) \le x_j + h_j, \ j = 1,\ldots, d\}$.

Comment: @angryavian Thank you, that solved the problem.